# padding on mnist for LeNet Architecture

Tags: deep-learning, numpy, mnist

LeNet accepts 32X32 image. So, to use LeNet for MNIST dataset,we have to change the size from 28X28 to 32X32. I came across [This](https://github.com/sujaybabruwad/LeNet-in-Tensorflow/blob/master/LeNet-Lab.ipynb) implementation. i am confused about how the following line of code work.

```
np.pad(X_train, ((0,0),(2,2),(2,2),(0,0)), 'constant')
```

Above line of code pad 28X28 pixed image to become a 32X32 image. Can anyone help me understand how exactly its done.

Comment: What dimension does X_train have and what is encoded in each dimension?

Comment: X_train is (10000,28,28)

Comment: its actually MNIST dataset loaded. so, its just gray scale image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it does exactly what you specify. The [used numpy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) appends values in each dimension. The amount of "pads" on each axis is specified by `((0,0),(2,2),(2,2),(0,0))`, given the dimension of your dataset, which is:

```
10000 (samples) x 28 (image dimension 1) x 28 (image dim. 2) x 1 (grayscale value!)
```

Now let's see what your specification means in that regard:

```
(0,0)Pad 0(as in the amount) values before and after each row
(2,2)Pad 2 before and 2 after each value of dim. 1 of your image data: 28 values -> 32
(2,2)Pad 2 before and 2 after each value of dim. 2 of your image data: 28 values -> 32
(0,0)Pad, again, nothing in the grayscale value dimension
```

That means you will end up with a 32x32 image in the respective dimension. Now, the only thing that's left is: *Which values do we pad?* The answer is quite simple, you do not specify any `constant_values`, meaning it will pad with the default `constant_values` (which is specified on the above linked page). Namely this value is 0.

To sum it up, simply imagine you have a 32x32 image, your 28x28 is in the middle, and on the outside you have a 2-value-thick border of 0's.